# Get all channels from a discord server and delete them with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is what I tried:

```
const guild = interaction.guild;
const channel = interaction.channel;
const channels = guild.channels.cache.array();
for (const channel of channels) {
  await channel.delete();
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> TypeError: guild.channels.cache.array is not a function

Answer (score -1):

According to Discord API, `guild.channels.cache` is an array of `GuildBasedChannel` objects. With that, you can easily do:

```
interaction.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
      channel.delete();
})
```

Comment: `guild.channels.cache` returns a manager which is a Collection

Comment: as Elitezen said, I think you could just access the channel's id by accessing the properties of the collection and delete it.